# Queueing System - Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory

Consider a supermarket with three cash settling boxes and only one queue created from buyers. Four people, A, B, C and D enter the supermarket at almost the same time and in that order. A, B and C go directly into service while D waits for the first avaliable cash box. Suppose that the service time for each cash box is exponentially distributed with mean $5$.

**How can I answer the following question:**
What is the probability D is the last one to leave?

Am I wrong if I try
P(D last one) = P(D last | cbox 1 first)*P(cbox 1 first) + P(D last | cbox 2 first)*P(cbox 2 first) + P(D last | cbox 3 first)*P(cbox 3 first)

So,

P(D last one) = P(T1 > max{T2,T3})*P(T1 < min{T2,T3}) + P(T2 > max{T1,T3})*P(T2 < min{T1,T3}) + P(T3 > max{T1,T2})*P(T3 < min{T1,T2})

And for independence:

P(D last one) = P(T1 > T2)*P(T1 > T3)*P(T1 < T2)*P(T1 < T3) + P(T2 > T1)*P(T2 > T3)*P(T2 < T1)*P(T2 < T3) + P(T3 > T1)*P(T3 > T2)*P(T3 < T1)*P(T3 < T2)

$$(\frac{1/5}{1/5+1/5})^4+(\frac{1/5}{1/5+1/5})^4+(\frac{1/5}{1/5+1/5})^4 = = 3(\frac{1}{2})^4 = 3\frac{1}{16} = \frac{3}{16}$$

Comment: Don't we want $\Pr(\min(T_1,T_2,T_3)+T_4)>\max(T_1,T_2,T_3))$? where $T_4$ is the service time of $D$?

Answer (score 1):

Setting $X_i$ the rv's of the service time of A,B,C and $Y$ the one for D you have to calculate

$$\mathbb{P}[\min(X_i)+Y>\max(X_i)] = \mathbb{P}[Y>\max(X_i)-\min(X_i)]$$

Comment: And what's the distribution of Y?

Comment: Is Y just the dist of the service time of any machine? $Y \sim Exp(1/5)$?

Comment: @JohnDanson Yes but independent of $X_i$. The $X_i$ now are ordered thus not anymore independent. To find the distribution of $Z=max-min$ you can use the order statistics. You can use the joint distribution of $(X_{(1)},X_{(3)})$ or the joint distribution of Range and Midrange

Comment: Am I wrong if I try
P(D last one) = P(T1 > max{T2,T3})*P(T1 < min{T2,T3}) + P(T2 > max{T1,T3})*P(T2 < min{T1,T3}) + P(T3 > max{T1,T2})*P(T3 < min{T1,T2}) ?

Comment: And for independence:

P(D last one) = P(T1 > T2)*P(T1 > T3)*P(T1 < T2)*P(T1 < T3) + P(T2 > T1)*P(T2 > T3)*P(T2 < T1)*P(T2 < T3) + P(T3 > T1)*P(T3 > T2)*P(T3 < T1)*P(T3 < T2)

Comment: $(\frac{1/5}{1/5+1/5})^4+(\frac{1/5}{1/5+1/5})^4+(\frac{1/5}{1/5+1/5})^4 = 3\frac{1}{16} = \frac{3}{16}$

Comment: by this way I could answer this question easily. But, of course, If i'm not wrong.